# using vba to create a specific number sequence in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet with squares down the side with the rest of the numbers filling in, as below:

1

2 3

4 5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12 13 14 15

16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24.....etc up to a big number

I'm having zero success here, so any help with this would be appreciated...

for an encore I then want to format the cells that contain prime numbers. I have some code here that I think will work if I get the above to work.

cheers for any help with this

Kevin

Comment: Zero success? What have you tried? Show us your code and tell us how it's going wrong.

Comment: 2 is a square ?

Comment: Oops, clearly not...

Comment: I tried @Gary's student code below. It works. Can you please share your code which highlights prime numbers. I'm learning VBA and just interested to see how your code works!

Comment: In VBA it's a little clumsy - I'm now using a the conditional formatting function below. Its an array function so needs CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER rather than just ENTER after putting it in the cell:                       =OR(A1=2,A1=3,ISNA(MATCH(TRUE,A1/ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&INT(SQRT(A1))))=INT(A1/ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&INT(SQRT(A1))))),0)))

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Just fill column **A** with the squares and then fill in each row with sequential values.:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    For i = 1 To 100
        k = 1
        For j = i ^ 2 To ((i + 1) ^ 2) - 1
            Cells(i, k) = j
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

which will produce:

[image]

*Just amend this code to mark the primes.*

Comment: Appreciate this a lot, cheers - simple when you know how!

Comment: @kevin_c  you are correct! ............the code is not complex.